# signed number behaviour in C

Tags: c, wav, endianness, stdio

I am working on some wave file sample extraction and I am stuck with my small part. I have 24 bit data being extracted from a sample, say `AB0293` (MSB being 1). I am using a 32 bit int variable to store this. I am unable to understand how to do this. What would happen to the MSB of this example in 32-bit format? And what would happen to the remaining bits?

The declarations are:

```
int32_t in2[10],in1[10];
FILE *fp1,*fp2;

fread(&in2[0],1,index1, fp1);//index1=3 
//value of in2[0] after this operation is 0xAB0293(-ve value of 24 bits)

fread(&in1[0],1,index1, fp2);
//value of in1[0] after this operation is 0xA00232(-ve value of 24 bits)

in1[0]=in1[0]-in2[0];//this is a 32 bit data operation(because of which i am getting wrong answer)
```

Comment: which compiler and architecture? Are you using `uint`?

Comment: What is "AB0293" ? Also, do you have some code?

Comment: It is normal to keep remaining 8 bits = 0. And don't understand what is the problem?

Comment: @i486 Depends. If we explicitly want signed behaviour, we would set the upper 8 bits to all 1s instead of all 0s...

Comment: @glglgl You are correct. But in this case the value is WAV file sample. It is 24-bit and there is no plan to make it 32 bit (extend it). It is only stored in 32 bit variable, if I have understood correctly.

Comment: Even your `fread(&in2[0],1,index1, fp1);` goes wrong if you make incorrect assumptions about both your file and your system/implementation. Better do it in a portable way...

Answer (score 2):

Sign extending a 24 bit value can be done directly this way:

```
int32_t sign_extend_24_to_32(int32_t value) {
    return value | -(value & 0x800000);
}
```

This does assume 2's complement for both the sample and the host CPU, and the availability of type `int32_t`, but that should not be a problem for the OP.

You read 3 bytes into the array elements `in1[0]` and `in2[0]`. You must initialize the array to `0`.  You also need to understand in which order the bytes are stored in the file (little-endian or big-endian) and which order the host computer uses.  Your current code assumes little-endian for both.

Answer (score 2):

The following assumes, since your problem statement is not quite clear:

- You have a file with sequences of 3 consecutive bytes (MSB first = big endian) representing 24-bit 2-complement values.
- You want to read these values into a signed 32 bit 2-complement value, where the most significant bit of the 24 bits is the sign bit.
- You want to keep the sign in the 32 bit value (i.e. want to extend the value from a 24-bit 2-complement to a 32-bit two complement value).

To make this independent of the endianness of your CPU, you read the values byte by byte.

```
#include <stdint.h>
...
uint8_t v[3];    /* Array to store a 24 bit value byte-by-byte. */
int32_t value;   /* Converted 32-bit value in machine endianness. */

if (fread (v, 1, sizeof v, fp1) == sizeof v) {
    /* Convert big-endian to machine endianness. */
    value = (v[0] << 16) + (v[1] << 8) + v[2];
    /* Sign extend when negative. */
    if (value & 0x00800000u)
        /* Fancy, non-undefined way to compute value |= 0xFF000000. */
        value = -((value ^ 0xFFFFFFu) + 1);
} else {
   /* fread found eof or error */
}
```

Comment: Your code assumes `INT_MAX >= 0xFFFFFF`.  A simpler non-undefined expression is `value -= 0x1000000;`

Comment: Thanks @chqrlie, I knew the explicit 2-complement computation would allow for a simpler solution. I'll leave it for educational purposes :-)

Answer (score 1):

Now that I see how you read from your file, a much cleaner way to do it is to be 100% clear about the endianness of your file and to choose the right function.

For big endian I immediately have the solution:

```
uintmax_t readarrayvalue(const char * data, uint8_t len)
{
    uintmax_t value = 0;
    while (len) {
        value <<= 8;
        value |= *(data++) & 0xFF;
        len--;
    }
    return value;
}
```

which you can use to read an arbitrary value out of an array in memory.

If the data in the array are in LE instead of BE, you can do something like

```
uintmax_t readarrayvalue_le(const char * data, uint8_t len)
{
    uintmax_t value = 0;
    uint8_t shift = 0;
    while (len) {
        value |= (((uintmax_t)(*(data++))) & 0xFF) << shift;
        len--;
        shift += 8;
    }
    return value;
}
```

The latter one is untested. Maybe it would be better to

- replace `shift` with `factor`, which is multiplied by 256 on every step
- do `value += (((uintmax_t)(*(data++))) & 0xFF) * factor;`

in order to avoid any issues.

Comment: note: this assumes 2's complement (for both the stored value and the C implementation)

Comment: @PaulHankin Thanks, forgot aboout that. I think I'll shorten my answer to the 2nd part.

Comment: `value |= (*(data++) & 0xFF) << shift;` does not work for `len > sizeof(int)`.  Furthermore, it invokes undefined behavior for `len == sizeof(int)` because of potential arithmetic overflow.

Comment: @chqrlie You are right. I just added a cast to `uintmax_t` which should eliminate both concerns.

Comment: The cast indeed fixes both concerns. Shifting is OK as long as you shift an unsigned value.  Multiplying would raised the same issue without the cast.